# How to pipe multiple results into a single command

Tags: powershell

I've got the following pipeline:

```
dir -recurse *.* | sls -pattern "matching_pattern" | select -unique path
```

Which gives me an output like this:

```
Path
----
D:\code\a.txt
D:\code\b.txt
```

I want it to call the command `gvim a.txt b.txt`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Where-Object` instead of `Select-String` for filtering the files, expand the `FullName` (or `Name`) property, so you get an array of paths or filenames, and [splat](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) it when calling `gvim`:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.* |
         Where-Object { (Get-Content $_.FullName) -match "matching_pattern" } |
         Select-Object -Unique -Expand FullName

& gvim @files
```

Replace `FullName` with `Name` in the `Select-Object` statement to get just the filenames without path.

---

If you want to stick with `Select-String` the approach would be similar:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.* |
         Select-String -Pattern "matching_pattern" |
         Select-Object -Unique -Expand Path

& gvim @files
```

Replace `Path` with `Filename` in the `Select-Object` statement to get just the filenames without path.

Comment: The `Where-Object` is matching on the filename, but I need it to match in the contents of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could access the two results by index:

```
$result = dir -recurse *.* | sls -pattern "matching_pattern" | select -unique path
gvim $result[0].FullName $result[1].FullName
```

Comment: I know I didn't say so, but I need something that works with an unknown number of matches.